# Generate duplicate Active directory on Server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, backup, data-recovery, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

Currently We are using window server 2008 r2 and installed Active directory on server, which working fine.

Problem is that, Some of roles which are not working well(Can not install/uninstall roles), So that I thinking to install new server and Make a copy of active directory from old to new. It is possible ?

How to make copy of full Active directory backup and restore OR Any other well option ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to:

1. Install AD server on a new server
2. Set up this AD server using "Add a domain controller to an existing domain"
3. Let AD's internal replication system perform a copy of your Active Directory for you
4. Remove AD from the old server (and reinstall WIndows and every app if needed).

You can use Windows Server's backup system to perform a backup of your AD (by backing up System State), but you should avoid restoring it to another server than the one it was taken from. Other option is a bare-metal recovery, but it will restore your server in the exact same state it was when the backup was taken.

Creating another DC is the best option: the system will copy everything for you and there will be no downtime on your network (at least, AD-wise).

Comment: I'd maybe talk a bit about domain controllers, DC-promo etc. Is the other one their only server? If so just taking it offline after moving AD would be a very bad idea. Top bits right though :-)

Comment: then window client will communicate with new AD server after performing above step?

Comment: @JoeTaylor suggested me, any good option if you have

Comment: @Joe: As far as I understand, ServerNinja only has one DC currently, so taking the first one offline aftter replication will bring the network in the same state as before - only with a working serv. But you are right, only one DC is bad.

Comment: @ServerNinja: If you replicate the AD by setting up a new domain controller in your network, **and** configuring your DHCP so that the new DC is advertised as a DNS, then basically yes, clients will use the new DC. You just have to install DNS with AD on the new DC (should have precised it in the first post).

Comment: What happen if Old AD server ip .50 and suppose new server ip .100 then AD<->client will working well?

Comment: Provided AD clients have IP .100 set up as DNS **and** DNS is installed on the new DC (IP .100), then yes, everything will work fine. You don't have to do any particular set up for DNS to work with AD and actually, AD asks you if you want to install DNS when you set up a new DC.

Comment: You need to at least transfer the FSMO roles over. You can't just drop a primary DC from the domain without serious issues. Look here for more information. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816944(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Also what runs your DNS / DHCP etc. Make sure you plan carefully a decomissioning process. It isn't as simple as spin a new one up, replicate AD, spin the old one down

Comment: Here is a reasonable guide to replacing your DC http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2010/10/09/remove-a-current-operational-domain-controller-from-active-directory/

Comment: @NathanShiraini I'm performing this but thing is that, DNS server and AD on single BOX, What happen If do above?

Comment: @NathanShiraini I need final Help, I've done 1.2.3 step and poweroff the old server(abc) but In new server, there are show two domain controller abc(DC) and xyz(GC). and Showing replication errors on event log; Can I delete abc(DC) then my domain will work? and xyz will make DC?

Comment: If replication did not occur smoothly, you should wait before removing the first server. Make sure everything is present on the new one (and I mean, EVERYTHING). Also, make sure you [do this](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc816779(v=ws.10).aspx) to make your new server an operations master. And make it a global catalog.